# Adding interest groups When creating new subsciber in Mailchimp API 3

Tags: php, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Hoping for some help as can't find an answer anywhere.

I am using the following PHP function to add a subscriber to mailchimp. This works fine. What I need to do is add the user with one or more group interests assigned. So for example I have a Group named "Test Group" which contains two interests "Test 1" and "Test 2". How would I amend the below function to include 1 or more interest values?

```
function mc_subscribe($email, $fname, $lname, $apikey, $listid, $server) {

    $auth = base64_encode( 'user:'.$apikey );
    $data = array(
        'apikey'        => $apikey,
        'email_address' => $email,
        'status'        => 'subscribed',
        'merge_fields'  => array(
            'FNAME' => $fname,
            'LNAME' => $lname
            )
        );
    $json_data = json_encode($data);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://'.$server.'api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/'.$listid.'/members/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Basic '.$auth));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/2.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    return $result; 

};
```

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/) contains enough information to figure this out, even though it doesn't say so directly.

You'll need to add an `interests` object to your request. It should take interest IDs as keys and boolean values as false. So you could update your code above as follows:

```
$data = array(
    'email_address' => $email,
    'status'        => 'subscribed',
    'merge_fields'  => array(
        'FNAME' => $fname,
        'LNAME' => $lname
    ),
    'interests'     => array(
        '9143cf3bd1': true
    )
);
```

Note that you'll need to get the IDs from the API, as there's no way to collect them from the web app, and also you should remove the `apikey` element from your request it is no longer used.

Comment: to get the group IDs use:
`curl --request GET --url 'https://us<X>.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/<LISTID>/interest-categories' --user 'abc:YOURAPIKEY' --include` that will give you the category IDs Now choose the category with the target group and do this:

`curl --request GET --url 'https://us<X>.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/<LISTID>/interest-categories/<CATEGORYID>/interests' --user 'abc:YOURAPIKEY' --include
`